# Is すしや and おすしやさん the same?

Tags: suffixes, food

I saw those words in the textbook Marugoto A1. There is no explanation, just some examples of those stores (すしや、うどんや、ピザや).

The ーさん ending suggest that is a person, maybe the person that cooks that dish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly same.
Appending さん after a store is common.
The latter is a more polite form.
However, the latter is not used in formal writing.

Comment: And おすしやさん sounds fairly childish. If you are talking to a little kid, then using おすしやさん may be better.